# Android shared preferences assignments not persisting between emulator sessions

Tags: android, xml, emulation, commit, sharedpreferences

I am using the following code to save data to my Android application's shared preferences:

```
    private SharedPreferences getOurSharedPreferences() {
        return getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }       

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getOurSharedPreferences();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(keyName, theString);
    if (!editor.commit()) 
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to save new string.");

    // Get it back as a test.
    String s2 = getStringFromStorage(keyName);
```

Where SHARED_PREFS_FILENAME is a private final static string and keyName is the name of whatever key I'm currently using as a field name.  The commit works fine, I don't get an exception.  As you can see I added a test that retrieves the recently committed string and when I check it (s2) the value is fine.  So I am not having any problems with shared preferences storage during the lifetime of my app.  However, when I relaunch the application in the emulator the shared preferences storage area is empty and I can't find the values I stored in the last emulator session.  I did some reading and as far as I can see the stored values should persist across sessions, apparently they are saved in an XML file belonging to the emulator.  Yet I am having problems.

Can anyone tell me why my shared preferences storage values are not persisting between Android emulator sessions?

-- roshcler

Comment: Are you seeing any errors or warnings in the stack trace related to your code?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but also testing in my device, I run my app, make some preferences changes, all OK, then I stop and restart the app and the changes have gone!

Comment: In my case I had my app running perfectly until I changed the package name, then everything works except sharedPreferences persistance. Is that your case too? did your app work until you changed something or it never worked before?

Answer (score 0):

On the Target tab of the debug configuration Dialog window, do you have "Wipe User Data" ticked?

Comment: Won't this remove the application itself?

Comment: I am asking if it is ticked, because if it is, it will wipe all user data.  And his user data is wiped, apparently, as his code appears to be solid.  :)

Comment: So if "Wipe User Data" is ticked, then even the app is uninstalled.

Comment: No, that is not my experience.  The installed applications should still exist.

Comment: I just looked and that box is not checked so no.  Is there anything else I might be doing that could accidentally clear the shared preferences store?  Thanks.

Comment: can you post the code that you use to recover the sharedPrefs, and when you execute it (onCreate/onResume)?
The code you have above should work as intended.

Comment: I am having the same problem too. I tried your "Wipe User Data" idea.  In the latest Eclipse that is now "Use same device for future launches".  I tried ticking that which did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try uninstalling the app and reinstall. Things can get corrupt in your shared preference files as you develop.

After I reinstalled my issues went away and I could see my persisted values across app lifecycles.